# create a custom function to use office.js

Tags: javascript, office-js

I'm developing a Microsoft word's add-ins. I need a function that get two parameter . first an array of index and second an array of length. this function must highlight text with that two parameter !!

```
function highlightForIndex() {
        Word.run(function (context) {
            var documentBody = context.document.body;
            context.load(documentBody);
            return context.sync()
            .then(function () {
                //here i need use my parameters
                //i am not sure what to do here !!!
                documentBody.font.highlightColor = "red";

            })
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log('Error: ' + JSON.stringify(error));
            if (error instanceof OfficeExtension.Error) {
                console.log('Debug info: ' + JSON.stringify(error.debugInfo));
            }
        });
    };
```

Comment: Hello, I  think i know what you mean, but please clarify, when you say "array of indexes" what is that index representing?  how are you creating such array?  What Stewart is proposing is right, you can search and highlight..

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you can't currently build a range using this method  What you could do is if you knew the text that you wanted to high light you could use the search function in order to get a range to that string and then highlight it that way off of the resulting range.